# CodedUI Test Builder Selection Items

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

When I use CUIT to select the item that will be coded it works,

but when I use another app (maybe coded in JAVA) it won't work, the  `Add assertions` can't select the `Menu` or the `button`, it selects **all** the window and it also can't define the `Control Type`.

[Screenshot of the problem](http://s11.postimg.org/s77lxhcgj/Untitled.png)

**Update :** If I need to log in the app and assert some data `username` and `Password`,  the Add Assertion can't select the `textbox` just select all the windows.

**Update 2 :** I work with start records on Coded UI Test Builder, and this the result code (Because I cant select the item), This code click on Menu Strip and the an item called Export, then a item with choice export to Excel

```
public void ExportExcel()
    {
        #region Variable Declarations
        WinClient uIMainthinkorswimbuildClient = this.UIMainthinkorswimbuildWindow.UIMainthinkorswimbuildClient;
        #endregion

        // Click 'Main@thinkorswim [build 1878.37]' client
        Mouse.Click(uIMainthinkorswimbuildClient, new Point(1358, 56));

        // Click 'Main@thinkorswim [build 1878.37]' client
        Mouse.Click(uIMainthinkorswimbuildClient, new Point(1263, 254));

        // Click 'Main@thinkorswim [build 1878.37]' client
        Mouse.Click(uIMainthinkorswimbuildClient, new Point(1137, 276));
    }
```

Comment: Could you show some of the code in your `UIMap.Designer.cs` file for the controls ?

Answer (score 1):

Java controls are not supported by CodedUI. You would have to try to write an extension for the custom controls.

You can find more information on that here... http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gautamg/archive/2010/01/05/1-introduction-to-coded-ui-test-extensibility.aspx

The technology of the controls you are trying to click are most likely not Web or MSAA.

If you are trying to use CodedUI with Excel (looking at your code) then you can find an example extension created for Excel here... http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gautamg/archive/2010/01/05/3-introducing-sample-excel-extension.aspx

Comment: thnx but I need to use CodeUI with Java, I will see Sikuli in C#